# How could we use a formula in query Google sheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-vlookup

I am unable to figure out how could we use formula within query results. I did not find any solution yet.

Like:

```
=query(sheet1!A1:Z,"Select A,B,Vlookup(D,sheet1!A1:A,1,false)");
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If your range is `A1:Z`, the column where you can insert the formula without error must be bigger than Z
2. Sheet formulas do not expect (nor allow) semicola at the end
3. If `D` is a string, it should be nested in double quotes
4. To combine your formulas, you need to combine the quotes correctly, e.g.:

```
=query(Sheet1!A1:Z, CONCATENATE("select A,B,",Vlookup("D",Sheet1!A1:A,1,false)))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't. you need to do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({sheet1!A:B, IFNA(VLOOKUP(D:D, sheet1!A:A, 1, 0))})
```

and then you can play with query:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({sheet1!A:B, IFNA(VLOOKUP(D:D, sheet1!A:A, 1, 0))}, "select Col1,Col2,Col3", 0)
```